# Entity Framework Core: How to configure model with two One to Many relations in one entity referencing the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to track who created an entity, and who edited (last) the entity. As I want to do this for each entity in my project, I am doing this in a base class called EntityBase.

If i uncomment the EditorUser in the EntityBase class with the corresponding ForeignKey attribute, the Context.Database.EnsureCreated method throws the following exception:

InvalidOperationException: 
Additional information: The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship that was detected between 'User.CreatorUser' and 'User'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property.

Can anyone help me configure the model to accomplish my requirements?

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CreatorUserId))]
    public User CreatorUser { get; set; }
    public Guid? EditorUserId { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey(nameof(EditorUserId))]
    //public User EditorUser { get; set; }
}
public class User : EntityBase
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
public class House : EntityBase
{
    public String Address { get; set; }
}
class Context : DbContext
{
    public Guid CurrentUserId = new Guid("3de85c1f-3ce1-4342-a582-83d6cc8e308f");

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<House> Houses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source = c:\Temp\eftest.db;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
        {
            relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityBase>();
        if (changeSet != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.Entity.CreatorUserId = CurrentUserId;
                        break;
                    default:
                        entry.Entity.EditorUserId = CurrentUserId;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically your `CreatorUser` in `EntityBase` is derived from `User` which uses `EntityBase` as base. So it's kinda a Chicken&Egg problem.
You can create another user entity for Parent and add that to `EntityBase` maybe.

Comment: That's it. Thank you for the answer.